# How to sort before using STUFF in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, sorting, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have 2 different values I'm trying to STUFF here. It is Quantity + Price. For example: 1-$0.36; 100-$0.29; 25-$0.31. How can I have it sort by Quantity before being stuffed? (1,25,100 instead of 1,100,25) I did come across this link [Sort data before concatenating using STUFF FOR XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077123/sort-data-before-concatenating-using-stuff-for-xml), but it dealt with 1 value and I'm dealing with 2 values

```
    SELECT STUFF(
   (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (5) 
        '; ' + (CAST(FLOOR(CASE WHEN PCFBD.Quantity IS NOT NULL THEN PCFBD.Quantity ELSE 1 END) AS VARCHAR)  + '-$' + CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(REPLACE(
       CASE WHEN PCF.PriceMethod = 0 THEN ROUND(I.CdCost / (100 - PCF.FormulaPercent) * 100, 2) 
            WHEN PCFBH.PriceFormula = 2 AND PCFBD.FormulaPercent IS NULL THEN ROUND(I.CdCost / (100 - PCF.FormulaPercent) * 100, 2)
            WHEN PCFBH.PriceFormula = 2 AND PCFBD.FormulaPercent IS NOT NULL THEN ROUND(I.CdCost / (100 - PCFBD.FormulaPercent) * 100, 2)
            WHEN PCFBH.PriceFormula = 1 THEN ROUND((I.ListPrice * (100 - PCFBD.FormulaPercent)) * .01,2)
            ELSE NULL END, '000' ,'')), ' ','0') + '', '.  ', '') AS VARCHAR))
 FROM              Item AS I 
 INNER JOIN        PriceContractFamily AS PCF ON I.FamilyId = PCF.FamilyId
                 AND I.ItemStatus IN (0, 5) 
 INNER JOIN        StockItem SI ON I.ItemId = SI.ItemId
                 AND SI.WarehouseId = '502E5876-C26B-4E11-8B88-AFE0C34ECF0D'                     
 LEFT OUTER JOIN   PriceContractFamilyBracketHeader AS PCFBH ON PCF.PriceContractFamilyId = PCFBH.PriceContractFamilyId 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN   PriceContractFamilyBracketDetail AS PCFBD ON PCFBH.BracketHeaderId = PCFBD.BracketHeaderId
 WHERE I.ListPrice = @ListPrice
AND LEFT(I.ItemNumber, 6) = @ItemNumber
AND PCF.PriceContractId = @PriceContractId  
 FOR XML PATH('')),1, 2, '') AS QtyPrice
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add an ORDER BY before the FOR XML PATH statement.